# How to remove newlines except appearing before certain characters

Tags: regex, string, text, replace

Using RegEx, I would like to remove all newlines `\n` except when followed by a hyphen `-`. In the actual file, there are hundreds of cases like this one. An artifact of copy/paste from a `PDF` document into `Markdown`.

See example below:

Before:

```
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
- do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
```

After:

```
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
- do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
```

Comment: `\n(?!-)` perhaps?

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No. Just using VS Code to replace with regex. Nick's solution worked like a charm.

Comment: @misaligar glad I could help. This question is pretty much a dupe so I won't post an answer